# Can I safely run a 6V DC air pump using a 9V Car adapter

Tags: dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

I have seen some general comments online about running a 6V DC motor on 9V Battery being OK. 
I am looking to run an air mattress pump originally designed for 4x 1.5V D batteries (6V DC) from a universal car laptop adapter. The lowest output voltage on the car adapter is 9V.

Nothing on the air pump motor mentions input power specs specifically. The only markings I can see are the following 3 lines and I get no hits googling each string.
hb-138-101 
rs-380ph-6016rb 
630301

The alternative would be to use an AC inverter and an DC 6v 2A adapter. It sounds like overkill to go from 12v to 120v AC just to get 6VDC, but so is running a car engine. 
Will I burn the motor if I ran it on 9V DC?

Comment: Something will overheat.  Possibly the 9V supply or the pump.  Get a 12 to 6V SMPS (Cheap online) Or MAYbe a 12W 6/12V? tungsten bulb in series or 24W/12V headlamp

Answer (score 1):

6v from 4 off D batteries will be 6volts or less, not 6v or more, when driving a reasonable load.

Depending how much you paid for the pump (so how well made it's likely to be), the commutator sparking, the bearings rattling, the windings and brushes over heating are just a few of the obvious wearout mechanisms that would be exacerbated by excess speed, voltage and load. The lifetime at 9v may be hours, or may be minutes. Are you feeling lucky?

Look on Amadong or fleaBay and find a DC to DC converter that *does* go down to 6v, they're not expensive. Cheaper to buy one before you destroy the pump rather than after, and another pump.

Answer (score 1):

> I can see are the following 3 lines and I get no hits googling each
>   string. hb-138-101 rs-380ph-6016rb 630301

According to [Mabuchi Motor](https://www.mabuchi-motor.com/)'s chart,

[image]

"rs-380ph-6016" is the designation for a carbon brushed '380' size motor with 16 turns of 0.6mm wire. Compare this to the '3-12V' [RS-380PH-4045](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=99) which has 45 turns of 0.4mm wire. Motor speed is inversely proportional to the number of turns, so your motor is probably rated for less than 6V. At 9V it will try to spin 50% faster and draw about twice as much power. If the 9V adapter can handle this then you risk burning out the motor.

The best solution is a 6V 'switching' regulator rated for sufficient current. A D cell is good for about 2A max, so hopefully the motor draws no more than 2A on 6V and something like [this](http://www.icstation.com/lm2596s-high-power-adjustable-step-down-module-with-digital-display-p-8858.html) should do the job.

[image]